# Import library is there but cannot be found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, cmake

Windows 8:

I have a library in a directory. The library is shared. I do something like this:

```
add_library(MyLib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION D:/Some/Location/for/lib)

...
add_executable(myExe ${myExe_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myExe MyLib)
```

The library is not found. I checked the paths, my folder contains a .lib and a .exp file. My lib, when compiled, is exporting the symbols.

The linker shows the lib in the command line:

```
/IMPLIB:"D:/Some/Location/for/lib/MyLib.lib"
```

But I get this error and I cannot figure out why:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyLib.lib'
```

I am not running out of disk space or have no permissions, so I cannot figure out what happens.

I tried to feed Microsoft visual studio 2012 with the full path to the .lib file. Still the same: not found. But it is indeed there. I can confirm it is there.

Comment: Are you mixing x64 and 32 bit?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but how could I check that to make it sure?

Comment: Did you select a 64 big generator in CMake? I mean Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64 will build a 64 bit application in Visual Studio 2012. If your MyLib.lib is 32 bit it will not work with your application. Visual Studio will give the exact error you mentioned in this case.

Comment: Ok. I opened visual studio to make sure I compile with 32 bits. I am generating 32 bits binaries all around and not mixing with any 64 bit lib.

Comment: Now let me check for the real exe, what I said is in the lib side, not the .exe.

Comment: The other options are path does not match the lib or the lib is corrupt.

Comment: No, the lib is not corrupt, I can run the tests in its own project. But look what I have here: Error 11 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyLib-NOTFOUND.obj' A .obj? I am not sure. I should have the dll in the same dir also? The .dll is elsewhere. In that dir there is only the .lib and .exp.

Comment: Do you have spaces in path?

Comment: No, I already suspected about that :)

Comment: @GermánDiago I know this is a super necro post, but I think you missed the `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` target property.